# Action returns PartialView rather than View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I've simplified the below for brevity.

When I click the actionlink, the action works successfully but returns only the partial view on it's own page rather than rendering it within the view. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

**PartialView ActionLink**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "_Partial1")
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View()
}

public ActionResult _Partial1()
{
    ...do stuff
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for something AJAX related if you want it to render within the view, or modify your view to use `Html.Render("_Partial1")` so it loads with the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Click" as below. Make sure you have reference to jQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Modify your Action Link as below.

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Click",                         // linkText
                   "_Partial1",                     // actionName
                   null,                            // controllerName
                   new { @class = "detailsLink" }   // htmlAttributes
                   )
```

Provide a  element where you want to render the content.

< div id="details" />

Invoke the below JS, so the content will be loaded in the  view or similar.

```
   $(function() {
      $('.detailsLink').click(function() {
        $('#details').load(this.href);
        return false;
      });
  });
```

This should invoke you partial action and renders the content on the same page.

Comment: Thanks Raj, that looks like a step in the right direction but still returns the same result. Is there more I need to do?

Comment: This code works for me. It might be some other code/scripts interfering.  Which view you calling the partial view? Also do you run any other scripts that might interferes? Best way to find out, remove everything else in your code and try to apply the my solution. If it works then add the bits until you can re create the problem. If that's still not working use a standard vanilla asp.net mvc app and get it working with my solution. What you have published in your question, according to that my solution works. Also be sure you have the jquery reference. Make sure you returning a partial view.